# Mongo aggregate nested lookup not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to `$lookup` a nested document with `aggregate`.

I'm trying to lookup the user who owns the shop associated with an order.

`Order`->`Shop`->`User`

But my aggregation query is returning an empty `userInfo` field.

Database:

```
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "shop": 1,
      "price": 11
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "shop": 2,
      "price": 101
    },
  ],
  "shops": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "user": "2"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "user": "1"
    },
    
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "country": "US"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "country": "UK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Aggregation:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "shops",
      let: {
        shop: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$shop"
              ]
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      as: "shopInfo",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$shopInfo"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        user: "$shopInfo.user"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$user"
              ]
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      as: "userInfo",
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "price": 11,
    "shop": 1,
    "shopInfo": {
      "_id": 1,
      "user": "2"
    },
    "userInfo": []
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "price": 101,
    "shop": 2,
    "shopInfo": {
      "_id": 2,
      "user": "1"
    },
    "userInfo": []
  }
]
```

How can I get the userInfo to populate?

[mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-FZgycQ1kcW)

Comment: You are matching strings with numbers in the 2nd `$lookup`. You can do a `$toString` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O0IRNuRwxnO)

Comment: Yes this was it!! X|

Comment: Maybe move the conversion into the `$let` for performance reasons? Otherwise I think you'll be doing a full collection scan on each iteration of the $lookup

Comment: @user20042973 I agree with you. Or maybe OP can simply refactor the schema to store all ids in either strings / numbers.

Comment: Kinda weird that `orders` collection has `"shop"` in the docs, but `"_id"` is used to `"$lookup"` into the `shops` collection?

Comment: Yes @rickhg12hs I that should be $shop in the lookup not _id! and I changed the schema to match, all are numbers now.

Comment: You could also shorten your aggregation pipeline by using `localField` and `foreignField` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4EOLTeV-ii5 "Link to mongoplayground.net example -->").